# What is the Reynold's number of a plate moving through a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers:_Stokes%27_drag) that the equation of resistive drag $F = -bv$ can be used, assuming the particle is moving

> through a fluid at relatively slow speeds where there is no turbulence (i.e. low Reynolds number, $R_{e}<1$)

In order to decide whether I can use $F = -bv$, I need to identify the Reynold's number of the rigid object I am working with.

In my case, I have a solid plate of width $w$, length $l$ and height $h$ which is moving perpendicular to the direction of the fluid at a velocity $v$. The fluid has a dynamic viscosity $μ$.

With the information mentioned above how can I calculate the Reynold's number of this rigid object?

Answer (score 1):

With the Reynolds Number:

$$\text{Re}=\frac{\rho v L}{\mu}$$

the characteristic length $L$ that can be used here is (e.g.):

$$L=\frac{l+h}{2}$$

assuming that $L \gg w$

> Why is the formula for the characteristic length $L$ what you have
> written it to be and why does $L$ need to be much bigger than $w$?

In many cases, the choice of a 'characteristic length' for the determination of $\text{Re}$ can be somewhat arbitrary and there's no 'hard and fast rule' to guide us. The case of a rectangular plate is such a case.

However, the point of transition from fully laminar to fully turbulent flow in terms of $\text{Re}$ number is not sharp. Here's [Wikipedia's note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number#Laminar%E2%80%93turbulent_transition) on this:

> For flow in a pipe of diameter $D$, experimental observations show that
> for "fully developed" flow,[n 2] laminar flow occurs when $\text{Re}_D < 2300$
> and turbulent flow occurs when $\text{Re}_D > 2900$. At the lower end of
> this range, a continuous turbulent-flow will form, but only at a very
> long distance from the inlet of the pipe. The flow in between will
> begin to transition from laminar to turbulent and then back to laminar
> at irregular intervals, called intermittent flow. This is due to the
> different speeds and conditions of the fluid in different areas of the
> pipe's cross-section, depending on other factors such as pipe
> roughness and flow uniformity. Laminar flow tends to dominate in the
> fast-moving center of the pipe while slower-moving turbulent flow
> dominates near the wall. As the Reynolds number increases, the
> continuous turbulent-flow moves closer to the inlet and the
> intermittency in between increases, until the flow becomes fully
> turbulent at $\text{Re}_D > 2900$. This result is generalized to
> non-circular channels using the hydraulic diameter, allowing a
> transition Reynolds number to be calculated for other shapes of
> channel.

Because of this uncertainty on $\text{Re}$, some uncertainty on $L$ is not problematic. Without direct observation, whether flow will be laminar of turbulent will always be a bit of and 'educated guess'.

Comment: Why is the formula for the characteristic length $L$ what you have written it to be and why does $L$ need to be much bigger than $w$?

Comment: I'll answer that as an edit to my answer, ta.

Comment: Another question: The rigid object in my question is falling down at a constant velocity $V$ through air in a room (the air is the fluid). The air in the room has no velocity. Can I assume that the $v$ in the Reynold's number equation is the velocity of the rigid object?

Comment: Absolutely: velocity is relative. Calculation of $\text{Re}$ is done for boats, ships, planes etc using these objects' velocity (or the relative velocity wrt the sea or air)

Comment: What about the growth of the laminar boundary layer along the plate and its collapse to a turbulent boundary layer at a Reynolds number based on the distance from the leading edge?

Comment: I think that can only happen when you're in or near the transient region.